# Host can't reach Internet if Guest VM is Host-Only

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet-connection

I have a problem with a VM in Virtualbox. I configure a VM in Virtualbox with Host-Only interface and until this point all goes well: the VM reach the Host and the Host reach the VM.
But there is a problem, why my host can't reach internet even if I shutdown the VM? I have Debian as SO in the host machine.

Here is my host configuration:

```
alessandro@al91:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:3a:02:xx:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:48:xx:e3:xx:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 79412sec preferred_lft 79412sec
    inet6 fe80::3f3:9d64:8e0a:839/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:xx:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
alessandro@al91:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.20 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: of the vm or of the host?

Comment: The host. It’s where stuff isn’t working as expected, after all.

Comment: I've just update the question.

Comment: I've update again the output.

Answer (score 2):

You have a “subnet conflict”. Both your real network (`wlan0`) and the VirtualBox Host-only adapter (`vboxnet0`) share the same subnet (*192.168.1.0/24*).

When connecting to Internet IP addresses, this doesn’t cause ambiguity, because the default route is bound to `wlan0`. However, before it comes to that, the PC would perform a DNS lookup to determine the IP address you want to connect to. I’m sure `/etc/resolv.conf` will show that it will try to contact *192.168.1.1* as the DNS server.

When connecting to local hosts, the default route is not used. Because your `wlan0` interface has a metric of “600” for whatever reason, it will not be used to connect to *192.168.1.1* – it is the more expensive route. However, your router cannot be reached via `vboxnet0`. DNS requests stall and it appears you cannot reach the Internet.

The solution is to change the subnet on the host-only adapter. On the command line, you can use `VBoxManage`:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0
```

In the GUI, go to File → Preferences → Network → Host-only Networks:

[image]

Double-click on the adapter you want to change, modify its settings and confirm:

[image: BILD]

Comment: thanks! Now my host reach Internet. I changed the Ip of the adapter `vboxnet0` because I think that it must be in the same subnet. Now the situation is this: host reaches Internet and VM, VM doesn't reach the host, is it normal? As you comment, I accept your answer

Comment: Depending on how your VM is set up, it may have a static IP address in the old subnet. But it’s of course not normal, otherwise the host-only adapter would be pointless. :)